# Moving Wordpress site to new domain - database import

Tags: database, mysql

Want to move a wordpress site to a new domain. 
So far I have downloaded the existing site files and exported the .sql database.

I have a fresh install of Wordpress on the new domain, can anyone explain the next steps in what order for moving the site across please?  I have tried a few things but the database import is failing via phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific. What kind of error do you get in phpMyAdmin. If you have a smaller site give [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin a shot. It simplifies the migration process and might save you time.

Comment: One more thing when you run the installer, under advanced options mark "deep link checking (slower)", just to make sure all file paths are fixed. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

For move a wordpress site to a new domain,

you have to follow below site. from there you will get proper way what to do next.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-wordpress-to-a-new-domain-without-losing-seo/

or

https://www.quicksprout.com/2015/09/16/the-simple-guide-to-moving-your-wordpress-site-to-a-new-domain/

best of luck.

Comment: is your problem solved from my answer?